# When does My Fairy mode unlock?

Tags: hyrule-warriors-legends

I have played 4 missions now and have yet to unlock My Fairy mode. When does this unlock?

Comment: Have you befriended any fairy yet?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I don't know, but from a google search everything indacates that before you can use the My Fairy mode you first have to meet and befriend a fairy. Whether or not there's special criteria for you to meet fairies I'm unsure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fairy Mode can be unlocked, in adventure mode, within G8: Defeat the Darknut Forces. The first faerie can be found in any of the normal pots that gives ruppees, so take some time and farm a little within that one. Also, if you press the "Y" button, you can change what shows on the map, allowing you to see if there is a Faerie, clothing, or food; along with rewards as well.

Answer (score 3):

In the map right above the starting area in adventure mode where the goal is to kill the Darknuts, i found the fairy in the South Field Keep in a yellow pot. it's in a bottle but it's like a drop.